# Android WebView Set Cookie fail (sessionCookie)

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I would like to set session Coockie

Im having problem with setting cookie in WebView. This is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, parent, false);

    String co = GlobalSession.SESSION_ID; //m4mg2aleunei8fad1lvn8h6n67
    String co_name = GlobalSession.COOKIE_NAME; //PHPSESSID

    //set and load web View

    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie("192.168.70.103", GlobalSession.SESSION_ID);
    cookieSyncManager.sync();



    WebView mView = new WebView(getActivity());
    mView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    mView.loadUrl("http://192.168.70.103/test.php");

    return v;
}
```

In previous step I send username and pass to server, which respond to me with parameters such as  SESSSION_ID and COOKIE_NAME...

in test.php I verify if the user is loged on.... Well its not, so I assume that setting cookie fails.
How to set cookie properly is my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the cookie incorrectly.
Use the following syntax:

```
cookieManager.setCookie("192.168.70.103", String.format("%s=%s", 
                  GlobalSession.COOKIE_NAME, GlobalSession.SESSION_ID));
```